# how to switch projects in firebase localhost:5000

Tags: firebase, localhost, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

Sorry I'm a newbie. I'm exploring firebase codelabs and successfully hosted a project using the localhost:5000. I'm creating a new project and also trying to use the `firebase serve --only hosting` but the project that was showing was the previous project. I tried `firebase serve --help` and also tried to search but just can't find the solution.

How can I delete the old project from localhost:5000 and use the latest project in the localhost:5000?

Answer (score 0):

Stop `firebase serve` by hitting control-c in the terminal where it's running.  You should do that whenever you're done working with your project.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This will be very useful. However, the project in the localhost:5000 is an old project and I cannot find the directory of the project to terminate it. I cannot find the files of the project in my computer. How to find the directory of the project or how to simply terminate the existing project in the localhost:5000?

Comment: Just reboot your computer. All existing firebase serve instances will go away. They will not come back automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot Doug :)

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find the directory of the old firebase project. I tried checking out powershell to terminate the port 5000. Powershell seems like not working, so I did not recheck if my localhost:5000 has been refreshed. Then I checked the firebase.json file of the new project, after "public", there is this "ignore" [...], I just deleted it because it looks like it should not be there is the codelab sample of friendly chat. Then i go to firebase directory of the new project and run firebase serve --only hosting. After refreshing localhost:5000 its now showing the new project. Wuhooo... I tried Ctrl+C to terminate the project but after refreshing localhost:5000 it is still showing the new project. I'm not sure if after terminating the project the localhost:5000 should be cleared or something. But anyway, at least the localhost is already showing the latest project. Not sure what went wrong or how it was resolved. Thanks @Doug Stevenson